# Is there a PHP function that can traverse an associative array and group it by common values/keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Associative array: `["Apple" => "Red", "Sun => "Red", "Grass" => "Green"]`

Change to: `["Red" => ["Apple", "Sun"], "Green" => ["Grassy"]]`.

Comment: No, not every single trivial operation imaginable has been granted its own function. This does not need more than a foreach loop with an assignment inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in, but one line of code will do it for you.
Loop the array and make the key value, and the value key

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $new[$val][] = $key;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Or

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) $new[$val][] = $key;
```

Returns

```
array(2) {
  ["Red"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Sun"
  }
  ["Green"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Grass"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/uTS3Q